# Pass option to tikz node based on page parity

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script, conditionals, xparse

**Story**: I've recently been creating a document with Koma Script with a moderately complex page layout.
There are different layers of content set with different commands declared in the preamble and it works quite well.
I've first created the layout (parts of it with a tikz overlay) of the odd pages and am happy with it for now. Next, I would like to migrate content to the even pages.
However, it appears that I am prohibited to use Koma Script's `\ifthispageodd{}{}` command in the options of a tikz `\node[options]`.

**TLTR**: So I would like to ask if anyone knows a way to **pass options** to a tikz `\node[options]` or `\draw[options]` command **depending on the parity** of the current page.

**Example**: I've attached a (non) working example
(also containing what appears to be a messy solution, namely to include the the whole `\node` statement in the `\ifthispageodd` arguments and then passing the respective options to it respectively -- the problem with minimal working examples is that they are *minimal*, so this option does not look so bad here).
The reader might argue that it is not really minimal since I could have dropped the `\NewDocumentCommand` and hence the `xparse` package and gone with `\newcommand`, but I seek a solution working with the former, since my layout relies upon this manner of creating commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

%\NewDocumentCommand{\testcommand}{O{}}{\ifthispageodd{\node[green]}{\node[blue]} at (0,0) {test} ;} %working, but a poor solution for large lists of options
\NewDocumentCommand{\testcommand}{O{\ifthispageodd{blue}{green}}}{\node[#1] at (0,0) {test} ;}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \testcommand
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \testcommand
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a style that uses `\Ifthispageodd` to select between two sets of styles.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/657453/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\tikzset{
  if page is odd/.code 2 args={%
    \Ifthispageodd{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
    }{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[if page is odd={blue}{green}] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\clearpage
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[if page is odd={blue}{green}] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks like an elegant solution and solves my question (and most of my problem in the background)! 
I would like to apply the same to the placement of the node `\node at (depposition) {content};` , but tikz tells me that 'no shape depposition' is known. From the pgf documentation vs 2.10 p 123 I infer that it has been searching for tikz keys and its last check is for shapes if no specific key is given, hence the error message.  Any idea on how to solve that? 
I may also post a separate question.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that this helped. For the 'no shapes, that means you're trying to refer to a node that doesn't exist. I'd need to see code to help beyond that, which would warrant a fresh question. To make placement use this answer's idea, you can use the 'at' *key* in the node options rather than using the 'at special syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a placeholder macro for each of the node options that you want to set (for example `\mycolor` for the color) and set the value using a helper macro that you call directly before `\node`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\setnodeoptions{%
\Ifthispageodd{%
\gdef\mycolor{green}%
\gdef\myfill{orange}%
}{%
\gdef\mycolor{blue}%
\gdef\myfill{red}%
}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\testcommand}{O{}}{\setnodeoptions\node[\mycolor,fill=\myfill] at (0,0) {test} ;}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \testcommand
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \testcommand
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Note that I changed `\ifthispageodd` to `\Ifthispageodd` following a deprecation warning from KOMA-Script.

If you actually plan to combine this with an optional `#1` that could consist of multiple node options then it becomes a little bit more complicated, in that case you could check inside `\testcommand` if the argument is given or not, if not then execute `\setnodeoptions\node[\option1,\option2,...]`, otherwise execute a separate `\node[#1]` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nicely commented answer! 
This answers my question and is a valid solution! 
I have, however, oversimplified my question and want to pass multiple optional arguments to the node that are used differently, based on the parity of the current page.  As you write yourself, this will become quite messy. @Andrew's answer appeared to be more flexible for that.